# SQL select from a table where all columns equal to value

Tags: sql

Is there a way to select everything in a database table where every column is equal to a value?

Suppose I have this table:

```
+-----------------------------+
|           people            |
+-----------------------------+
|  id  | name |address|  age  |
+------+------+-------+-------+
|1     |Arnold|  USA  |   31  |
|2     |Andeng|  PHI  |   18  |
|3     |  Bea |  UK   |   52  |
+------+------+-------+-------+
```

and the SQL statement would be like:

```
SELECT id, name, address, age 
FROM people 
WHERE id, name, age, address LIKE '%$value%'
```

I do hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, you need to test each value independently:

```
SELECT id, name, address, age
FROM people
WHERE id LIKE '%$value%' AND
      name LIKE '%$value%' AND
      age LIKE '%$value%' AND
      address LIKE '%$value%';
```

First note.  This assumes that the columns are strings.  `LIKE` should only be used on strings (explicitly convert other types if necessary).

Second note.  If you are passing parameters into a query, use *parameters*.  Don't munge the query string.

Comment: This won't go over well if the columns are not all string type.  I think having this need might indicate bad table design.  But upvoted because you used the word `munge`.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT id, name, address, age 
FROM people 
WHERE 'value' in (id, name, address, age);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, address, age 
FROM people 
WHERE id = 'value' 
AND name = 'value' 
AND age = 'value' 
AND address = 'value';
```

Comment: hey there! Thanks for providing an answer. Please also add some explanation to it, although it might seem obvious at a first glance, it might also puzzle some users. Cheers!

Comment: Anybody know if there's a shortcut to check all columns without checking each manually? seems like a common use case